# Shell script not saving output of SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, bash, shell, sqlplus

I have changed from a RHEL server to CentOS, a shell script that was working no longer works. The CSV file is empty but when I copy and paste the SQL in to SQLPlus I get 100's of rows?

```
    #!/bin/bash

    function getdata
    {
    sqlplus -s user/pass <<EOF
    SET COLSEP ,
    SET LINESIZE 10000
    SET PAGESIZE 50000
    SET NEWPAGE NONE
    SET HEADING OFF
    SET FEEDBACK OFF
    SET ECHO OFF
    SET TRIMSPOOL ON

    select distinct orders.order_no, orders.order_total from orders;

    exit;
    EOF
    }

    getdata | sed 's/,\s\+/,/g; s/\s\+,/,/g' > output.csv
```

Comment: Is there a carriage return problem? Can you check the end of your lines? And what happens if you remove the `sed` filter?

Comment: You may need to add a SPOOL command, e.g. SPOOL myfile.csv.

Comment: @BriteSponge this will be the correct answer. I'm presuming they mean they get 100 rows on the terminal screen, and not in output.csv like they want.

Comment: No don't want to spool, used to work without that since we pipe output to `> output.csv`, spool is to do it direct in SQLPlus which we don't want since we process the data using `sed` after.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set `set serverout on`

Also look for ^M characters in your script, these creep up when copied from say `RHEL --> Windows --> CentOS`. Just a thought.